# How can I create and integrate Human Task into BPEL Workflow using WSO2 BPS?

Tags: wso2, task, bpel

I'm trying to create and integrate Human Task into BPEL workflow. So far I've found only one sample of human task integrated with WSO2 BPS but it doesn't show how to create it, it's just ready to deploy and execute. Does anyone know if WSO2 has recently released new tools/methods to create and integrate Human Task into BPEL?

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the following blog posts and articles they might help with your work

http://nandikajayawardana.blogspot.com/2013/05/how-to-implement-your-own-task-ui-on.html

http://wso2.org/library/wso2con2013/integrating-people-to-workflows-and-applications-with-human-tasks

http://ddweerasiri.blogspot.com/2011/01/create-business-processes-human-tasks.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however, it's not answering my question. from your first link, I followed the tutorial from that blog but got stuck because the link containing the wsdl's is just not working and the author is not replying about it. The second link just explains in general terms about the human tasks with BPEL but there's no specific information on how to create them. The third link is just not explaining the human tasks creation at all. I'm hoping for WSO2 team to provide information on thi issue soon.

Comment: please refer to http://docs.wso2.org/display/BPS320/Writing+a+Human+Task+Artifact and see if this is what you are looking for. let me know is this works for you