# How to Create and Deploy a BPEL process with Human Tasks using wso2 BPEL

Tags: bpel, wso2

I have not found any documentation regarding creation of `BPEL` process with Human Task using `WSO2 BPEL`. There is just once example called `Claims Approval` existing which is ready to deploy process. The documentation of creating that example process was also not there.

Please help me out. Have found a similar question existing but unfortunately there was no answer for that question. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Greetings
Karthik

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create and integrate Human Task into BPEL Workflow using WSO2 BPS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16765947/how-can-i-create-and-integrate-human-task-into-bpel-workflow-using-wso2-bps)

Comment: Nope.. I was refering to the same question in my post as well! There was no appropriate answer :(

Comment: Ok, next time please also link to the question you refer to. Otherwise, we can only guess and will probably flag your question as duplicate again.

Answer (score 1):

Please fing documentation on at Claims Approval [1].

Regarding human task process creating , from [2] you can find about implementing a human task event listener.

And sample BPEL process on Apache ODE( Which is underlying BPEl engine on wso2 BPS) can be found at[3].

[1]. http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/BPS300/Claims+Approval+Task+Sample

[2]. http://tryitnw.blogspot.com/2013/05/humantask-event-listeners-wso2-bps.htm

[3]. http://wso2.com/library/articles/writing-simple-ws-bpel-process-wso2-bps-apache-ode

Comment: In the first link, the Claims Approval is a ready to deploy example! I saw this before, there is no explanation about how the process is created!

In the Second link, the author concentrates on human task event listener and NOT about creation of human task process!

I know how to create a simple bpel process which invokes services.

No where it is documented step by step procedure of how to create a simple human task and the corresponding changes needed to be done :(