# adding custom workflow extensions to Wso2 API manager

Tags: wso2, bpel

I have recently started working on WSO2 API manager and I have added a user signup workflow to it by following on this link :

https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM180/Adding+a+User+Signup+Workflow

It was pretty simple and straightforward, but the thing is, in my case I am the admin as well as the user. So Once I send a signup request, I manually log on to `workflow-admin` console and approve the request and once i approve the request I can login to the API Store. But in a typical production environment, the admin as well as the user must get some kind of email notification so that they can approve/reject as well as login once request is approved. How do I achieve this kind of scenario wherein the user will get an email notification once his/ her request has been approved as well as the admin will get a notification once a request is sent?

I have checked the adding a workflow-extension module in the documentation:
 https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM180/Adding+Workflow+Extensions

But i'm still trying to figure it out.
Looking forward to some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I finally got it working.
Write a class in java similar to **UserSignUpWSWorkflowExecutor**.java, make sure it extends the **UserSignUpWorkflowExecutor** class in the *org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow* package. And now in the complete method of your class, check for the signup status and write the logic for sending mail here. After this step make a jar of the particular package/component and add it to the patches directory in binary file of wso2 API Manager, while doing so make sure the name of the jar is similar to the one in the plugins directory. After this Step start your API Manager and in the admin console there is a workflow-extensions.xml file. Edit that file and add give the name of jar that you just created along with its package name. save it and restart the API Manager.
Note : Enable the user sign up worflow executor by following this link first
https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM180/Adding+a+User+Signup+Workflow

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the current release of the Business Process Server doesnt have support for email notifications for HumanTasks. But this will be available from the next release of the Business Process Server (v3.5). As a work around what you can do is create a service in the ESB to send out emails and create a BPEL workflow (with humanTasks) which will trigger this email service in the ESB. But if you can wait till the next release (which should be available by end of Aug), then this feature would be available with the new Business Process Server.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I am following this link wherein a email notification  is sent when a subscription is created https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM180/Customizing+a+Workflow+Extension and somehow this doesnot seem to work. also according to your answer, how do i create a BPEL Workflow with human task which will trigger the email service in esb? I dont have much clarity on this. I am following this link :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17944822/how-to-create-and-deploy-a-bpel-process-with-human-tasks-using-wso2-bpel

Comment: I was able to create an API which provides email service, that is it can send email notification to a given user. But i'm still clueless on how to create a BPEL workflow with human task that can trigger this particular email service in ESB. I have followed several links, but nothing gives me a clear cut idea on how to proceed further. I need to capture the event in the workflow-admin portal i.e the admin can either approve/reject the request and email notification has to be sent to appropriate user. Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Break the problem into 2. 1st write a BPEL that can invoke the email service [1] . 2nd Create a human task for the BPEL workflow and pass a URL from which the admin can approval the flow. This example would help you with that [1] http://thiliniishaka.blogspot.com/2012/10/develop-ws-bpel-process-using-wso2.html    [2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/BPS320/Claims+Approval+Task+Sample